# strtoupper function not working for Russian

Tags: php, locale

The code is the following:

```
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'ru_RU' );
echo strtoupper('Hello! Привет!');
```

Latin characters transforming as expected. But Russian - stays unchanged.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to read something about UTF-8: http://allseeing-i.com/How-to-setup-your-PHP-site-to-use-UTF8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`mb_strtoupper()`](http://php.net/mb_strtoupper) instead:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'ru_RU');
echo mb_strtoupper('Hello! Привет!');
```

Output:

```
HELLO! ПРИВЕТ!
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Hji1Sf)